# glm::dot product returns unexpected value

Tags: c++, glm-math, dot-product

I am facing the following problem. In my code I am dealing with a -1.#IND000000000000 value. Going into debugging seems that this value is returned by a division 0/0. In order to solve this problem, I tried to figure out why I have these unexpected 0 values. It turns out that the glm::dot product doesn't work as expected. I have the following code:

```
double jacobian = 1.0;
double baseGeom = fabs(dot(baseDir, n1)) * fabs(dot(baseDir, baseN0)) / baseDist2;
double shiftGeom = fabs(dot(shiftDir, n1)) * fabs(dot(shiftDir, tri->N)) / shiftDist2;
jacobian *= (shiftGeom / baseGeom);
```

In my case both shiftGeom and baseGeom are two float numbers equal to 0.0 and this should be the illegal division. Indeed my resulting jacobian is equal to -1.#IND000000000000. Therefore, I went backwards. We can just take into account the baseGeom float and the first inner dot product: dot(baseDir, n1).

According to the debugging, my baseDir vec3 has values:

```
baseDir.x = -0.98280960321426392
baseDir.y = -0.18137875199317932
baseDir.z = 0.034456323832273483
```

while the vec3 n1 has values:

```
n1.x = 0.024055255576968193
n1.y = 0.059235699474811554
n1.z = 0.99795418977737427
```

by manually doing the dot product:

```
n1.x *= baseDir.x;
n1.y *= baseDir.y;
n1.z *= baseDir.z;
double result = n1.x + n1.y + n1.z;
```

I have that result = -7.0025885090529982e-010. However, the glm::dot gives me back as result 0.00000000000000000. What do you think is the error?

Comment: it is a floating point accuracy problem; if you change to `glm::dvec3`, you'll get double precision math and your desired result

Comment: Did you make sure your baseDir and n1 vectors are using the double type for storage? If I had to guess I would say your values are getting converted to float and you're loosing precision. I'm not familiar with jacobians but can you simply scale your vecotors so you have bigger numbers and more precision?

Comment: You are both right.. it seems that vec3 uses float values and converting it to glm::dvec3 as @m.s. suggested solves the problem.. so, does it mean that the result given by the glm::dot is a float as well (since I am doing the dot product between vec3 vectors which use float values) and therefore the whole number can't be contained in a float but I need a double?

Comment: It is possible for the dot product to produce zero if the vectors are at right angles. Therefore you need to be able to accept a zero.